# "Nucis vado"? Going nuts?

Tags: vocabulary

Does "Nucis vado" mean going nuts? I go of a nut?
Some folks want to use it as a motto and I would like to make sure it is proper.
If not, what would "Going Nuts" be, properly translated?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5):

Literally, yes, "I go of a nut". It's basically nonsense in Latin; "go nuts" is an English idiom that means nothing in other languages.

If you want a term for going mad/crazy, the first source I think of immediately is Aeneid IV, which has some good descriptions:

> *ardet amans Dido traxitque per ossa furorem*
>   Dido is burning with love, and her madness has been drawn deep into her bones

(IV.101, trans. mine)

This suggests the noun *furor* or the verb *furere*. If you want a participle, "raving" or "being insane", that would be *furens*; this is used in the title of a Seneca play, *Herculēs Furens* ("Hercules the Mad"), where he's driven into a rage by Lyssa and murders his family.

If you want a more prophetic madness, here's Lucan describing the Oracle at Delphi:

> *bacchatur demens aliena per antrum / colla ferens*
>   Out of her mind, she raves through the cavern, a strange force gripping her neck

(V.169-70, trans. mine)

This suggests *demens*, "out of [your] mind", or *bacchans*, "raving, wanton". The latter evokes the Bacchants, priestesses of Bacchus who would throw themselves into ecstatic frenzies for religious reasons; the former is very literally "out of one's mind" (*de* + *mens*).

Out of the three, I think *bacchans* is probably closest to your intended meaning, since it brings to mind parties and revels; if someone is using it as their motto, that's probably the type of madness they have in mind. (Though the Bacchants could sometimes be just as murderous as Hercules in their frenzies: they're the ones who killed and dismembered Orpheus when he refused to sing for them.)

P.S. *Bacchans* is specifically a singular form: if multiple people are going mad, they're *bacchantes*. This holds for the other suggestions, too: just replace the final *-s* with *-tes* to make it plural.

Answer (score 1):

*Nucis vado* is ungrammatical in Latin. There are some adverbal uses of Genitive, a typical adnominal case, but your example is not a possible case: clearly, *nucis* cannot express the result of a verbal change predicate like *vado*. There are many ways of translating *to go nuts* or *to go crazy* into Latin: e.g., by using the deadjectival verb *īnsānīre* (derived from the adjective *insanus*) or the denominal verb *bacchārī* (derived from the noun *Bacchus*). Interestingly (from a linguistic point of view), the English analytic expression *to go nuts* or *to go crazy* typically corresponds to a synthetic expression in Latin: cf. the abovementioned deadjectival and denominal verbs.